# Calculating initial, transition and emission probabilities in HMM

Tags: java, probability, hidden-markov-models

I have a fully labeled data set of observations and their corresponding states ( assumed to be in arrays).Then I need to calculate initial, transition and emission probabilities for this data set. Are there built-in code with any Java library that can be used here ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check out [jahmm](https://code.google.com/p/jahmm/)?

Comment: yep. Best thing was to calculate by my own.

Comment: @AnoAPI can you share your implementation?